# Implementing IEnumerable with an Array

Tags: c#, ienumerable

This is likely a simple syntax question, but I can't figure it out.

Normally, I would do this:

```
public class OrderBook : IEnumerable<PriceLevel>
{
    private readonly List<PriceLevel> PriceLevels = new List<PriceLevel>();

    public IEnumerator<PriceLevel> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return PriceLevels.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return PriceLevels.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

But instead of a list, I want to use an array - like this:

```
public class ArrayOrderBook : IEnumerable<PriceLevel>
{
    private PriceLevel[] PriceLevels = new PriceLevel[500];

    public IEnumerator<PriceLevel> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return PriceLevels.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return PriceLevels.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` seems to compile fine - but the public `IEnumerator<PriceLevel>` says that I need some kind of cast - what is the best way of doing this?

William

Comment: Why? Why use an array for this?

Comment: `List` is backed up by an array itself, so you're not gaining anything, except an overcomplication of your work.

Comment: @Tudor depending on what other logic goes in the class, it might make more sense for `PriceLevels` to be an array (e.g. a fixed size).   Nothing wrong with wanting to refactor that.

Comment: Yea - this is a gross oversimplification of something larger and long story short it needs to be an array (at least for now)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class ArrayOrderBook : IEnumerable<PriceLevel>
{
    private PriceLevel[] PriceLevels = new PriceLevel[500];

    public IEnumerator<PriceLevel> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return PriceLevels.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return PriceLevels.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: The type can be inferred.  `.AsEnumerable()` works just fine.  `T[]` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, but its public method for `GetEnumerator` returns a weakly-typed `IEnumerator`.

Answer (score 6):

As you can see from your own `IEnumerable<T>` implementation, you need to provide both a generic and non-generic version of the method to fulfill the interface.  In order to do this, since the methods have the same signature, one of them needs to be an explicit interface implementation.  In the case of `List`, the generic version is a method in the class and the non-generic version is an explicit interface definition, since the generic version is generally more useful.  In the case of an array, it already had the non-generic version as the implementation, and it was adding the generic version of the method in a subsequent version.  To avoid the breaking change, the generic version is the explicit interface definition instead.

There are a number of ways of solving this issue.  Here are three simple ones.

```
public IEnumerator<PriceLevel> GetEnumerator()
{
    return PriceLevels.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
}


public IEnumerator<PriceLevel> GetEnumerator()
{
    IEnumerable<PriceLevel> enumerator = PriceLevels;
    return enumerator.GetEnumerator();
}

public IEnumerator<PriceLevel> GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IEnumerable<PriceLevel>)PriceLevels).GetEnumerator()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Cast `T[]` to the corresponding `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
    public IEnumerator<PriceLevel> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<PriceLevel>)PriceLevels).GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

According to ECMA-335 Partition I, §8.9.1, a vector type (single dimension array like `T[]`) implements `IList<T>` which implies that it also implements `IEnumerable<T>`. However the implementation of the methods is explicit, so you'd need to use one of these:

Option 1: Simply use the implicit assignment of arrays to `IList<T>`.

```
private IList<PriceLevel> PriceLevels = new PriceLevel[500];
```

Option 2: Leave the member variable as an array, and use the `AsEnumerable` extension method. This extension method uses a supported implicit assignment which is preferable to using a direct cast like `(IEnumerable<PriceLevel>)PriceLevels`.

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()  
{  
    return PriceLevels.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();  
}
```

Items to avoid:

1. The `Cast<T>` method introduces an unnecessary type check for each element of your array and should be avoided.
2. If you need to only include non-null elements from the enumeration, it's OK to use the `OfType<T>` extension method. Otherwise, this method also introduces an unnecessary type check on each element.